# given an image and its fourier transform, find another image fft using fourier properties

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform, computer-vision

I managed to solve few of those questions , but I'm not manage to answer 3 of them correctly,

the question is: given an image and its fourier transform, find another image fourier transform ,using fourier properties to explain why it would look like that.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the same problem in 1-dimension and you will be able to find the answer.

Hint: If you know the Fourier transform of a delta function (or time-shifted delta function) and the Fourier transform of a rectangular window, then you should be able to answer the above problem.

P.S. Cannot comment because I need 50+ reputation to do so.

Comment: well the first one is a circle convolved with deltas, circle is that weird big circle in fourier, and deltas is a sin function, so I will get a circle with some lines of black with the first.
the second one is not clear to me, if you can edit your comment and explain I will vote it up. thanks @Maxtron